# Intellisense said error: member "Class::field" is inaccessible but it's still works? Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, operator-overloading, intellisense, member

I have a class in separate file from my main.cpp that overload insertion operator. My class is written like this:

Person.h

```
#ifndef PERSON_H_INCLUDED
#define PERSON_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

class Person{
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Person&);
    public:
        Person(std::string);
    protected:
        std::string name;
};

#endif
```

Person.cpp

```
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

Person::Person(string name){
    this->name = name;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Person& person){
    out << "Name\t:" << person.name << "\n";    // Here's intellisense said error.
    return out;
}
```

Right at `person.name` Intellisense said error. My points are:

- Why it said error but my code still works and built properly?
- Is it a bug or something I do wrong?

(I'm using visual studio 2010)

Comment: Intellisense errors are not necessarily compiler errors. Intellisense is a separate compiler that partially compiles your code to help create completions in the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: So, is it okay to ignore that kind of error?

Comment: It is. Probably it is not aware of the `friend` to the full extent.

Comment: I do see something blow up in a *very* nasty way when I try the snippets.  Be sure that your .cpp file contains `#include <string>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine!

It's a false error, try a clean build, ignore it if it persists and check for *Visual Studio* updates.